# MVC Compare not working

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, data-annotations

I'm having problems validating 2 textboxes using the [Compare-attribute. Even if they're same the client validation says they're different.

In my editmodel I have:

```
[Required]
[DataType(DataType.Password)]
public string Password { get; set; }

[DataType(DataType.Password)]
[Compare("Password", ErrorMessage = "Password not matching")]
public string ConfirmPassword { get; set; }
```

In view:

```
<tr>
    <td class="editor-label">
    @Html.LabelFor(model => model.User.Password):
    </td>
    <td class="editor-field">
         @Html.EditorFor(model => model.User.Password)
         @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.User.Password)
    </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
       <td class="editor-label">
           @Html.LabelFor(model => model.User.ConfirmPassword):
       </td>
       <td class="editor-field">
           @Html.EditorFor(model => model.User.ConfirmPassword)
           @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.User.ConfirmPassword)
       </td>
    </tr>
```

Textboxes gets rendered as:

```
    <input class="text-box single-line password" data-val="true" 
           data-val-required="Password missing" id="User_Password" 
           name="User.Password" type="password" value="" />

    <input class="text-box single-line password" data-val="true" 
          data-val-equalto="Password not matching" 
          data-val-equalto-other="*.Password" id="User_ConfirmPassword" 
    name="User.ConfirmPassword" type="password" value="" />

<span class="field-validation-valid" data-valmsg-for="User.ConfirmPassword" 
data-valmsg-replace="true"></span>
```

What might be wrong/missing here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I updated unobtrusive + jquery validation using the Nuget packagemanager. And that did the trick