# Compare field not showing error message

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I have got a model as below -

```
public string Password { get; set; }
[Compare("Password", ErrorMessage = "Password and Confirm Password have to be the same")]
public string ConfirmPassword { get; set; }
```

In my HTML, I am adding the code as

```
<label>Password</label>
<span class="req">*</span>                                  
@Html.PasswordFor(x => x.Password, new { @class = "form-control form-control2", @required = "required" })
<p class="signuppace"></p>

<label>Confirm Password</label>
<span class="req">*</span>
@Html.PasswordFor(x => x.ConfirmPassword, new { @class = "form-control form-control2", @required = "required" })
```

The message for the required field gets displayed but here the ErrorMessage "Password and Confirm Password have to be the same" doesn't get displayed. I have already referred this [1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6818516/compare-password-attribute),[2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20002074/mvc-compare-not-working) SO links.  What am I doing wrong? Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The don't think that the helper adds markup to display a validation error automatically, other than for client side validation using unobtrusive client validation which executes using JavaScript (Not server side).

You want to use `@Html.ValidationMessageFor(x => x.ConfirmPassword)` to show the error message or simply check for the error using the `ModelState`.

```
@if (ModelState.Errors["ConfirmPassword"] != null && !string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(ModelState.Errors["ConfirmPassword"][0]))
{
    // Display the first error message for this field
    ModelState.Errors["ConfirmPassword"][0]
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You don't show all relevant cshtml, but you need to display the validation message.

Either use `@Html.ValidationSummary(excludePropertyErrors: false)` to display all validation errors in one place, or put `@Html.ValidationMessageFor(x => x.Password)` near your input field.